# Help with jQuery issue

Tags: jquery

I have a simple page with a list of items. I am allowing users to vote on these items, but I only want to allow the user to vote once per. item.

I made a jQuery script that adds a class to the items the user has voted on:

```
if(!$(this).find(".item span").hasClass("voted")) {
  $(".item").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".ratingbar").hide();
    $(this).find(".votebar").show();
  }, function() {
    $(this).find(".votebar").hide();
    $(this).find(".ratingbar").show();
  });
};
```

This is the script that prevents the user from voting again on the same item.

```
$(".votebutton").click(function() {
  $("div#"+offerid).find(".item").addClass("voted");
});
```

This isn't working. When hovering an item, the hover function still runs even though the second script successfully added the class "voted" to the html.

Why can this be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) (or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)) to prevent this, since [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) attaches to the DOM element, the fact that it's class changes doesn't unbind those `mousenter` and `mouseleave` event handlers (this is what hover actually binds to).

However, [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) evaluates if the class matches **when you hover** (because it works off event bubbling, so it checks if the selector matches before executing), and will do what you want, like this:

```
$(".item:not(.voted)").live('mouseenter', function() {
  $(this).find(".ratingbar").hide();
  $(this).find(".votebar").show();
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).find(".votebar").hide();
  $(this).find(".ratingbar").show();
});
```

There's no reason to do the `if` statement, this will work for all elements and you should only run it once.  Previously it was checking if the *current* item had the `voted` class...but then applying the hover to all `.item` (`n` number of times) elements for each one that didn't have the class...instead run this just once outside whatever loop you're in now, it should be directly in a `document.ready` handler.

**Edit:** You can shorten this as well since you're just toggling the elements around, using [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), it's the same effect, just a bit simpler/more concise:

```
$(".item:not(.voted)").live('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $(".ratingbar, .votebar", this).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! After upgrading to jQuery 1.4, this worked perfectly :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the class `voted` later in the code, but your `.hover()` bound the events `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` to the `.item` already.

If you want your stop your event handler from continuing on if the element has the `voted` class, you can check for the class and return early from the event handler:

```
$(".item").hover(function() {
  // save this variable so we don't need to call $() three times
  var $this = $(this);
  // stop processing the event if the item has the 'voted' class
  if ($this.is('.voted')) return; 

  $this.find(".ratingbar").hide();
  $this.find(".votebar").show();
}, function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  // note - you might still want to process this event as they mouse out after voting?
  if ($this.is('.voted')) return; 

  $this.find(".votebar").hide();
  $this.find(".ratingbar").show();
});
```

**Or** after voting you can remove the event handlers:

```
$(".votebutton").click(function() {
  $("div#"+offerid).find(".item").addClass("voted").unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
});
```